# Is investing in an ETF generally your best option after establishing a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, etf

It seems that many people recommend investing in an ETF when you just start out with a Roth IRA at a very early age. I was wondering why this is so, and if there are some better or complimentary options out there as well?

Since I'm looking for a very-long term, compounded investment, I'd prefer a little safety, or at least the ability to not lose sleep at night due to daily or individual market fluctuations. Thanks :)

Comment: Since you're looking for a very-long term compounded investment, I'd say its a good time to take some risks...

Comment: I don't know anything :(. So your thoughts about ETFs are that they're low-risk, stable (but less-reward) than other options out there?

Comment: @littleadv - would you mind if you could explain what types of investments you are referring to by that statement? I was seeing if you were trying to suggest something that's considered better for long-term compounded investment than most mutual funds and ETFs. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkTemplar "most mutual funds and ETFs" is a meaningless sentence.

Answer (score 5):

ETFs are a type of investment, not a specific choice. In other words, there are good ETFs and bad. What you see is the general statement that ETFs are preferable to most mutual funds, if only for the fact that they are low cost. An index ETF such as SPY (which reflects the S&P 500 index) has a .09% annual expense, vs a mutual fund which average a full percent or more.

sheegaon isn't wrong, I just have a different spin to offer you. Given a long term return of say even 8% (note - this question is not a debate of the long term return, and I purposely chose a low number compared to the long term average, closer to 10%) and the current CD rate of <1%, a 1% hit for the commission on the buy side doesn't bother me. The sell won't occur for a long time, and $8 on a $10K sale is no big deal. I'd not expect you to save $1K/yr in cash/CDs for the years it would take to make that $8 fee look tiny. Not when over time the growth will overshaddow this.

One day you will be in a position where the swings in the market will produce the random increase or decrease to your net worth in the $10s of thousands. Do you know why you won't lose a night's sleep over this? Because when you invested your first $1K, and started to pay attention to the market, you saw how some days had swings of 3 or 4%, and you built up an immunity to the day to day noise. You stayed invested and as you gained wealth, you stuck to the right rebalancing each year, so a market crash which took others down by 30%, only impacted you by 15-20, and you were ready for the next move to the upside. And you also saw that since mutual funds with their 1% fees never beat the index over time, you were happy to say you lagged the S&P by .09%, or 1% over 11 year's time vs those whose funds had some great years, but lost it all in the bad years.

And by the way, right until you are in the 25% bracket, Roth is the way to go. When you are at 25%, that's the time to use pre-tax accounts to get just below the cuttoff.

Last, welcome to SE.

Edit - see sheegaon's answer below. I agree, I missed the cost of the bid/ask spread. Going with the lowest cost (index) funds may make better sense for you.  To clarify, Sheehan points out that ETFs trade like a stock, a commission, and a bid/ask, both add to transaction cost. So, agreeing this is the case, an indexed-based mutual fund can provide the best of possible options. Reflecting the S&P (for example) less a small anual expense, .1% or less.

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is between *index* ETFs, *index* mutual funds, ETFs, and mutual funds?

Comment: 'Cause in your edit you referred to "(index) funds" and I was confused which of the four that was referring to, if any of them makes any sense >.<

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what to tell you without knowing income, age, marital status, etc., so I'll give some general comments.

ETFs come in all varieties.  Some have more volatility than others.  It all depends on what types of assets are in the fund.

Right now it's tough to outpace inflation in an investment that's "safe" (CDs for example).  Online savings accounts pay 1% or less now.

Invest only in what you understand, and only after everything else is taken care of (debt, living expenses, college costs, etc.)  A bank account is just fine.  You're investing in US Dollars.  Accumulating cash isn't a bad thing to do.

Comment: Single, sophomore in college, have a little bit of money left over (about $500~$800) after thoroughly taking into account the utility bill, possible emergencies, transportation, etc)

Comment: I know the answer is going to be something like "Wait until you graduate and have a job", but then what financially useful thing can I do with that money other than just keep it in the savings account, which earns *less* than the rate of inflation? :(

Comment: This depends on what you understand (per my last paragraph).  Do you understand the risks/rewards of peer-to-peer lending, for example?  That can do better than inflation, but it's a bit trickier to get right.  That's just one example.  Other activities have a greater reward possibility, but they're not passive.  Spending time starting up a website is one example of that.  And on and on.

Answer (score 1):

When investing small amounts, you should consider the substantial toll that commissions will take on your investment. In your case, $800 placed in just one ETF will incur commissions of about $8 each way, or a total of 2% of your investment. I suggest you wait until you have at least $5000 to invest in stocks or ETFs. Since this is in a IRA, your options are limited, but perhaps you may qualify for a Vanguard mutual fund, which will not charge commissions and will have annual expenses only a trivial amount higher than the corresponding ETF. it should probably go in a mixed allocation fund, and since you are young, it should be a relatively aggressive one. Mutual funds will also allow you to contribute small amounts over time without incurring any extra fees.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to research and compare. As Jack Bogle is considered the father of the EFT, I checked VFINX, the Vanguard S&P 500 fund. .17%. Not bad, but the min investment is $3000. On the other hand, Schwab has its own branded ETFs which have no trading cost. Whatever Kaitlyn chooses to do, there will be a tradeoff, at least in the early years.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Vanguard's target retirement date funds have a minimum of just $1000.  In any case, one's options are fairly limited with so little capital, but the advantage of the mutual fund is that once one has $3000, one can costlessly add to it in increments of just $100, whereas the ETF will incur an $8 trading charge for **every subsequent trade**.

Comment: Schwab's S&P 500 ETF has a .08% expense compared to the Vanguard target dates .19%, and no commission to buy or sell.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The bid/ask spread is probably greater than that 0.11% difference.  I'm not trying to say you have to invest in mutual funds, just that it's not so clear cut, and for most small investors, research show that mutual funds are cheaper.

Comment: Hmm. You may be right. Schwab S&P mutual fund SWPPX .09%.